D3D12 CubeMap DDS Loading (CreateDDSTextureFromFile12)
Working on a D3D12 renderer, using Franck D Luna book about D3D12.
I'm trying to load a DDS file which is a cube map.
I use DirectX::CreateDDSTextureFromFile12, from DDSTextureLoader h/cpp I've found in the book source code.
auto cmdList = std::make_shared<CommandList>(renderer->GetDevice(), renderer->GetHeaps(), D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE_DIRECT);
    cmdList->Begin();
    
    HRESULT hr = DirectX::CreateDDSTextureFromFile12(renderer->GetDevice()->GetDevice(), cmdList->GetCommandList(), L"Assets/skybox2.dds",m_cubeMap.Resource, m_cubeMap.UploadHeap);
    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        LOG(Error, "failed to create dds texture !!!");
        std::string errorMsg = std::system_category().message(hr);
        LOG(Error, errorMsg);
    }

    auto ShaderHeap = renderer->GetHeaps().ShaderHeap;
    m_cubeMap.Handle = ShaderHeap->Allocate();
    
    D3D12_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srvDesc = {};
    srvDesc.Shader4ComponentMapping = D3D12_DEFAULT_SHADER_4_COMPONENT_MAPPING;
    srvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D12_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURECUBE;
    srvDesc.TextureCube.MostDetailedMip = 0;
    srvDesc.TextureCube.MipLevels = m_cubeMap.Resource->GetDesc().MipLevels;
    srvDesc.TextureCube.ResourceMinLODClamp = 0.0f;
    srvDesc.Format = m_cubeMap.Resource->GetDesc().Format;
    renderer->GetDevice()->GetDevice()->CreateShaderResourceView(m_cubeMap.Resource.Get(), &srvDesc, m_cubeMap.Handle.CPU);

    cmdList->End();
    renderer->ExecuteCommandBuffers({ cmdList }, D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE_DIRECT);

    renderer->WaitForGPU();

My resource seems to be correctly uploaded to the GPU (visible in NVidia NSight) and I have no error whatsoever, but the texture is completely black. I would like to understand why and to fix it

The book version is a bit hacked up from an older version of my code, so I'm not sure what exactly is happening here. You can find the latest version on GitHub (h/cpp) and the docs are here. You can also use the full DirectX Tool Kit for DX12 which includes a version integrated with a resource upload handler.
